# Assembly x86: LEA and MOVSB changes my Source String?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm doing a program in Assembler x86 (Intel 32 bits in Windows). I'm making a program (for Homework) in which I have to cipher a string, which I'll iterate by blocks conformed by two characters. I use EBX to move through the source string, increasing it by 2. For now, I didn't go into the ciphing part of the program, since I'm having trouble with problems smaller than that. Thing is, when a block has the same character, like "AA", it doesn't need to go through the cyphing process, so I have to copy "AA" to the result string as it is. This is how I do this:

```
CypheLoop:
call VerifyBlock
cmp byte[caracblock], 0
je End
cmp byte[caracblock], 1
je AddLastCharacter
cmp byte[caracblock], 2
je AddNoCiphedBlock
jmp CipheLoop
```

VerifyBlock takes care of seeing how a block is conformed, it changes "caracblock" to a number depending on its characteristics. 0 means the block is empty (Meaning that the string is over), 1 means that it's only one character in the block (For example "ABC", would have a block with just "C"), 2 if the characters of the block have to be copied as they are (As described before, another case would be if the block has a space in it), or 3 if the block needs to be ciphed.
Up to now, things work great! The program adds the characters and finishes when expected, however, **AddNoCiphedBlock has some unexpected behavior**, it looks like this:

```
AddNoCiphedBlock:
    mov esi, 0
    mov edi, 0
    mov ecx, 2
    lea esi, [sourcestring + ebx]
    lea edi, [resultstring + ebx]
    rep movsb
    add ebx, 2
    jmp CipheLoop
```

The problem is not what it returns (Although what I got is not what I expected) but the source of the problem is that, for some reason, the source string is altered. If I write "AA", I get "AA", correct. If I write "AABB", I get "AABB", that is correct. If I write "AABBCC", I get "AABBAA". The source string, after using AddNoCiphedBlock, changes to "AABBAA", and it continues to get worse. **This is what happens to the source string through the process**.

```
AABBCC
AABBAA
AABBAA
AABBAABB
AABBAABB
AABBAABBAA
```

Why is this happening? I'm just copying something from the source! Both my Source String and Result String are in the .bss section as "sourcestring resd 1" and "resultstring resd 1". I use _gets to get the source string. I'm trying to give as much explanation and detail as possible, I can't even grasp the reason of why it goes wrong like that.

Comment: Probably your source and result strings overlap.  Did you only reserve 1 byte of space each with `db 0` or something?  Look at the pointer values after LEA to make sure `absolute_value(EDI - ESI) >= ECX`, otherwise your copy overlaps.  (unrelated: `mov esi, 0` is useless, you're already overwriting the old value with `lea`.)

Comment: I declared both strings in .bss as resd 1.

Comment: I noticed that eventually; it would have been a lot easier to see if that was part of your [mcve] code block.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to the site and I'm still getting around it, not much of a pro at programming yet. And I did what you told me. And it's all okay, EDI - ESI >= ECX.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert *at programming* to ask a question, but you do have to think about it from the POV of readers.  Try to make your example code block self-contained.

Comment: Also, I thought at first you were copying the whole buffer but you're not.  So that EDI-ESI >= ECX condition is bogus.  ECX isn't correlated with the size of your buffer or the length of the input.  So nevermind that.  What matters is simply the input overflowing the buffer.  Removed that part from my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I increased the buffer size to a 100 of both result and source strings, I think that has to be enough, but it solved the problem. Means a lot

Comment: `gets` can read arbitrarily many bytes.  If this is anything but a toy / learning exercise for your own use, it's impossible to allocate a buffer large enough to be truly safe for `gets`.  (e.g. if input is redirected from a file that doesn't contain newlines).  ISO C and C++ removed `gets` from the language because there's no safe way to use it unless you already know what the input is going to be, or at least the format.  Good programs should check for input format errors, not crash on them.  And BTW, I added a section to my answer about how to debug problems like this.

Comment: It was something I had to do for university, the whole subject depended on it. I don't think they will need to input a string with a buffer larger than 100. They will try "Hello World" or common phrases. Again, I really appreciate the help, I wouldn't have been able to finish it, as it was starting to get frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You used `gets` and buffers only 4 bytes long (`resd 1`), and you overflow them.**

When your string is 4 input characters or longer, the terminating `0` byte is outside the buffer.  (`gets` stores 5 bytes total: the data plus a terminator.  The 4 `'A'` bytes go in `sourcestring: resd 1` and the terminating `0` is the first byte of `resultstring: resd 1`.

If they're adjacent, then copying the the first 2 bytes of src to dst *overwrites* the `0` byte of src because it's also the first byte of dst.

**Use (much) larger buffers,** and/or use a function that takes an upper limit of how many bytes to read (a buffer size).

---

### How to debug this:

Once you know a byte is changing that you expect not to change, set a watch point on that address in your debugger.  Then it will stop at the instruction that changes it.

In your case, that'll be the terminating `0` byte at the end of `"AABB"`.  The address is `sourcestring+4` because it comes after the 4 ASCII bytes.  Then let it run and you'll see it stop at the `rep movsb`.

Also, you might notice while doing this that your buffer is only 4 bytes long so `sourcestring+4` is outside the 4 byte buffer, and/or that the address is the same address as `resultstring`.

---

Code review:

`mov esi,0` is useless; you already overwrite EDI using `lea`.  Also, using `rep movsb` for a fixed-size 2-byte copy is hilariously overcomplicated.

```
    movzx eax,  word [sourcestring + ebx]      ; 2-byte load
    mov   [resultstring + ebx], ax             ; 2-byte store
```

Or if you insist on `movs`, use `movsw` once.  (Not `rep movsw` so you don't have to set ECX).